# how to add folder to a listbox in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, listbox, directory, addition

i have a list box and i want to add a folder/directory to that which is at the specified location i have used the code

```
 string path = "E:\\shruti\\MyDir";
 DirectoryItem folder = new DirectoryItem(path);
 lstBurnItems.Items.Add(folder); //add folder to listbox
```

but its not working fine...
what should i do to get success??

Comment: Are you trying to add the contents of the folder? Or just the folder name?

Comment: What is your list box supposed to display?

Comment: Could you be more specific about "not working fine"?  Are you encountering a compile-time error?  Runtime error?  Or just wonky behavior?

Comment: i want to add folder containg files in it to my listbox named lstBurnItems...

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513391/how-to-show-a-windows-folder-contents-in-a-windows-form-using-net

Comment: u r not getting my question.. i need to add already existing folder that is not blank its having files in it...and i want to add it to listbox...simply..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an example showing how to add folders within a folder to a `ListBox` and to add Files within a folder into a `ListBox`. Sorry, you weren't clear so I gave both.

```
        string path = @"E:\shruti\MyDir";

        string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(path);

        // For folders in the directory
        foreach(string dir in dirs)
            lstBurnItems.Items.Add(dir);


        // For files in the directory
        string[] dirFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path);

        foreach (string file in dirFiles)
            lstBurnItems.Items.Add(file);
```

Comment: thanks...i have one more question.. can we add the complete folder that is containing files in it to list box...MyDir is the folder that is containing some files and i want to add it to the listbox  what is the method??

Comment: my listbox is blank initially...
at run time i want to add complete folder  to it..

Comment: Using the example code above, put the foreach (string file in dirFiles) into the foreach (string dir in dirs) loop and this will answer your question.  It will loop through each folder and add all files to the listbox.

Comment: why u have wriiten to add folders within a folder to a listbox?? i just want to add a single folder whose path i have specified..to a listbox..as an image..so that it should contain all the files that are within that folder.

Comment: As an image? Are you trying to build a tree?